# Error starting a VirtualBox instance inside an Ubuntu VirtualBox instance

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I am trying a Microservices demo that uses Vagrant to start up a VM and deploys software to the started machine.

Because the demo is set up for Linux and I am using Windows (8.1 Pro), I am running the demo in a VirtualBox container on my Desktop, I am using the latest Ubuntu Desktop - V15.04

Vagrant gives an error, and upon investigation I found that the VirtualBox inside my Ubuntu instance is not starting. The error message I get from the VirtualBox GUI inside my VM is "VERR_VMX_NO_VMX", i.e. it is complaining that virtualisation is not available to it.

I have verified that my host machine does have a CPU capable of virtualisation, and it is enabled in my BIOS.

I also checked the Virtualbox file and it has virtualisation enabled:

```
<Hardware version="2">
   <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
   <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true"/>
   <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
   <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
   <HardwareVirtExUX enabled="true"/>
   <PAE enabled="false"/>
   <LongMode enabled="true"/>
   <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="true"/>
   <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>   
    </CPU>
```

My question: What can I do to get VirtualBox inside my guest Ubuntu to work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is called nested virtualization.  Unfortunately, Virtualbox does not support it right now.  You can follow the feature-request on the Virtualbox ticket [here.](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032)

The "HardwareVirtEx*" configurations you are looking at refer to the top level Virtualbox installation and if it can use the hardware virtualization features of the CPU.  My understanding is it has nothing to do with support for nested virtualization.

One possible workaround might be to use VMWare or another virtualization platform that does support nested virtualization.

Good Luck!